# Armazenar dados da table no dispositivo.

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para uma empresa onde realiza pedidos de refeição, essa aplicação é em PHP, como sou novo na área queria saber se é possível ter a base de funcionários salvo no tablet, assim ao digitar a matricula do funcionário ele carregar o nome sem precisar fazer uma requisição no servidor, afim de consumir menos dados móveis.
Sei lá ter uma lista ou array que teria essa informação.

Comment: Não. O `PHP` não consegue trabalhar com arquivos ou base de dados no lado do cliente. **Talvez** a melhor solução para seu caso seja utiliza `js`.

Comment: Pode criar um JSON em JS e pesquisar o nome pela matrícula.

Comment: Só um adendo: A depender do tamanho da sua base de dados, talvez isso nem valha a pena. Só para ter ideia, uma api que retorna nome, email, id, avatar, cidade, estado, país, situação (status), datas de criação e modificação consome cerca de 800 bytes, com GZIP esse valor pode chegar a 400 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Em PHP não é possível fazer isso, afinal PHP é uma linguagem web que roda somente no lado do servidor. Uma forma de fazer isso seria o desenvolvimento de um aplicativo que pode ser em android por exemplo, e utilizar um banco SQLite no celular/tablet para armazenar os funcionários, mas mesmo com essa solução o aplicativo ainda teria que fazer algumas requisições para atualizar seus registros caso um novo funcionário fosse adicionado a base de dados.
Normalmente quando desenvolvemos alguma aplicação em PHP que sera usada por alguma empresa espera-se que a empresa forneça um pacote de dados maior para os funcionarios, ou que a aplicação seja usada internamente utilizando uma rede Wifi ( em caso da utilização ser por dispositivos móveis ).